# Prepared statement not sending data or img to db

Tags: php, html, image, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am attempting to create my first prepared statement. I had most of my query working properly before doing this, but everyone told me I should do it this way to prevent SQL Injection.

I'm trying to send product info to my database. Included in this data, I am trying to send an img file and have it moved into my db. Before attempting this prepared statement I was doing a simple mysqli insert statement and the only part of my query that did not work was getting the file name of the img to show up in my database as the actual file name. The way it was uploading was as "array" or "1". I changed things around to try to make it work with the procedure statement the best I could.

I'm not too sure if my attempt to upload the img file is correct in this prepared statement or not. The reason being is none of this is even being sent to my data base now. I am not getting any errors with my database connection. After I click submit it acts as if it sent, but nothing appears in it.

I start it off with validation for what I am entering into my db.

```
<?php
//Validation
if(Input::exists()) {
   if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'product_id' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 50,
            'unique' => 'products'
        ),
        'name' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'price' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'saleprice' => array (
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'final_price' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'shippingprice' => array (
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'category' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'item_details' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 1550
        ),
        'item_details2' => array (
            'max' => 1550
        ),
        'description' => array (
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 1550
        )

    )
    );
```

I then process the form info. I'm not sure if my $file variable is structured right for sending the file name to the db.

I get this error with the php error info on..
Notice: Undefined index: img in /home4/pfarley1/public_html/addproduct.php on line 90

```
//Create
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if($validation->passed()) {
        if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
            $product_id = trim( $_POST['product_id'] );
            $name = trim( $_POST['name'] );
            $price = trim( $_POST['price'] );
            $saleprice = trim( $_POST['saleprice'] );
            $final_price = trim( $_POST['final_price'] );
            $shippingprice = trim( $_POST['shippingprice'] );
            $category = trim( $_POST['category'] );
            $item_details = trim( $_POST['item_details'] );
            $item_details2 = trim( $_POST['item_details2'] );
            $description = trim( $_POST['description'] );
            $viewproduct_type = trim( $_POST['viewproduct_type'] );
            $date = ( $_POST['date_created'] );
  //line 90 $file = ($_POST ['img'] [move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"productpics/". $_FILES['file']['name'])] );

        //Connection
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
        /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }



        /* create a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO products ('product_id', 'name', 'price', 'saleprice', 'final_price', 'shippingprice', 'category', item_details', 'item_details2', 'description', 'viewproduct_type', 'date', 'img') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {


            /* bind parameters for markers */
            $stmt->bind_param('isiiiisssssis', $product_id, $name, $price, $saleprice, $final_price, $shippingprice, $category, $item_details, $item_details2, $description, $viewproduct_type, $date, $file);

            /* execute query */
            $stmt->execute();

            /* bind result variables */    //Not sure what to put here?
            $stmt->bind_result($district);

            /* fetch value */     //or here??
            $stmt->fetch();



        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}   
?>
```

The form

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="product_id">Product ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="product_id" class="smallinputbar" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="name">Product Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="price">Product Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="price" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="saleprice">Sale Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="saleprice">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="final_price">Final Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="final_price" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="shippingprice">Shipping Price</label>
            <input type="text" class="smallinputbar" name="shippingprice" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="category">Category</label>
            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="category" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="item_details">Item Details</label>
            <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="item_details2">Item Details 2</label>
            <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="item_details2">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <input type="message" class="messageinput" name="description" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="viewproduct_type">View Product Type</label>
            <select class="optionbar" name="viewproduct_type">
                <option name="notSelected">Not Selected</option>
                <option name="viewproduct_type" value="a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id">Standard</option>
                <option name="viewproduct_type" value="Option">Option</option>
            </select>
        </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
            <label for="button">

            <input type="submit" id="button" name="create" value="Create New Product">
            </label>

        <span class="floatright">
            <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile">
            <input type="submit" name="create" id="signinButton" value="Upload">
        </span>
</form>
```

I followed examples from the php manual and youtube, but none are really like what I am doing, especially with adding in the img file upload.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong with my prepared statement or the way I am trying to upload the img file? I've been stuck in the img file upload for a long time and have tried a million different ways and I'm hoping this way will work or if I could get guidance on a way to fix what I'm doing.

Comment: Try this:
if ($stmt = mysqli->prepare($con, "INSERT INTO products ('product_id', 'name', 'price', 'saleprice', 'final_price', 'shippingprice', 'category', item_details', 'item_details2', 'description', 'viewproduct_type', 'date', 'img') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

Comment: @Joci93 I tried that originally. I get a parse error when having the ->...Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->'

Comment: You don't need the bind_result and fetct() codes, because you insert data. Delete these lines in your code:  /* bind result variables */    //Not sure what to put here?
            $stmt->bind_result($district);

            /* fetch value */     //or here??
            $stmt->fetch();

Comment: @Joci93 I took those out and still the same result with the same error pointing to line 90. $file = ($_POST ['img'] [move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"productpics/". $_FILES['file']['name'])] );